# Apple TV content per country

Tags: appletv

I am considering the Apple TV.
The problem is, all the promotions about Apple TV have been very US-centric, so I'm afraid of buying a useless device (I already have a Chromecast).

Is there a matrix that shows which content providers and features are available per country?

Answer (score 1):

To add on to grgarside's answer, you may be able to determine if certain content provider apps are available in your country by using a website that lets you browse the tvOS App Store, such as [App Sliced](http://appsliced.co/apps/newest/tv) or [148apps](http://www.148apps.com/newest-148-app-store-additions/5/any/). From the app listing, click on it to view the iTunes web listing for it, and it should say it's not available in your country if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of most Apple TV pages is the following message:

> Some features may not be available in all regions or all languages.

The simplest way to check if your region is supported by an Apple TV feature is to go to [apple.com/choose-your-country](http://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/) and select your region, then go to the Apple TV pages for that country and see which features are available.

There are a couple of support pages which list the countries where certain features are available:

- Search app

  The Search app in tvOS lets you search for the following content in these countries:
  https://support.apple.com/kb/ht205321
- Siri

  Siri is available in tvOS in the following countries and languages:
  https://support.apple.com/kb/ht205300#languages